# Hebrew translation of The Lord of Hosts?

Tags: names

Is YHWH Tzevaot the correct Hebrew translation of The Lord of Hosts?

In the example from wikipedia: YHWH Elohe Tzevaot, is YHWH the specific God, Elohe just god and Tzevaot hosts? (The god YHWH of Hosts?)

Comment: Is this on topic? It asks for a translation so it seems to be only about language, but the words are inherently religious ones possibly asking for religious explanation.

Comment: @Danno but it concerns understanding Torah

Comment: "Lord of Hosts" _is_ the translation.

Comment: @Daniel, exactly. -1 as completely backwards and about Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In prayer or when reading the Bible out-loud, it would be pronounced "Adonoi Tzeva'ot", as Jews do not pronounce the [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton).

In conversation or a study session, Jews would prefer not to use either of those sacred names, so they would say "Hashem Tzevakot."

Comment: +1 for noting that Tzevakos is actually part of the name. Too many people I've heard say it as Tzeva-os even in casual conversation.

Answer (score 0):

YHWH, which we refer to as the [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton#Usage_in_religious_traditions) is the most holy name of God in our tradition. It seems to be translated into English as “the Lord” or “the Eternal”. The accepted [Jewish concept expressed by the Tetragrammaton](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%94) is “He was, He is and He will be” and so the better translation is “the Eternal”.

Literally  Tzevaot means hosts. It is also a name of God. The [Gemoro Berochos 31b](http://www.halakhah.com/rst/zeraim/01a%20-%20Brochos%20-%202a-31b.pdf) explains the use of this name by Hannah when she prayed to God for a child:

> And she vowed a vow and said, O Lord of Zebaoth [Hosts].(7)  R.
>   Eleazar said: From the day that God created His world there was no man
>   who called the Holy One, blessed be He, Zeboath [hosts] until Hannah
>   came and called Him Zebaoth. Said Hannah before the Holy One, blessed
>   be He: Sovereign of the Universe, of all the hosts and hosts that Thou
>   hast created in Thy world, is it so hard in Thy eyes to give me one
>   son?
>   NOTE (7) I Sam. I, 11.

So  “YHWH Tzevaot” is the correct Hebrew translation of “The Lord of Hosts” or better it would be the translation of “The Eternal of Hosts”.